# How to install tensorflow with anaconda in windows?

Tags: tensorflow

I tried to install tensorflow with anaconda in windows and I have got an error:

*(tensorflow2) C:>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl*

*tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.*

at first i tried to have tensorflow with native pip but had errors there too, and at the end i came to anaconda and this error happened.
if there is anybody who knows about this i will be thankful if gives me a hand.

Comment: I do it on linux, but isn't it just `pip install tensorflow` or `pip install tensorflow-gpu` on windows as well?

Comment: actually yeah, but when i tried an example and wrote at the first line: "import tensorflow" it didn't work consequently i tried anaconda

Answer (score 0):

May I know your python version? If your python version is 3.6 and if you are trying to install 3.5 tensorflow version you might get this error.

Make sure to use this command when you are creating the anaconda environment

```
conda create -n name python=3.6
```

Then use the above pip command inside the environment and it would be fine then.

Here I have created a small video tutorial about this particular problem here: [How to Install Tensorflow Using Anaconda in Windows - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNWQN_g_ZsI)

If you have any more questions just let me know